# Style background image with JS not working

Tags: javascript, css, getelementsbyclassname

Ok, maybe its a stupid question with a little bug, but I'm trying fix this and I can not:

```
    <style>
 .pagar a {   
 width:  200px;
 height: 85px;
 display: block; 
 background-image: url('imagens/pagar.jpg'); 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;

     } 
.pagar a:hover { 
 background-image: url('imagens/pagar-hover.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat; } 
</style>

    <script>
    function clickado() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('pagar')[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url("imagens/pagar-clickado.jpg")';
    }
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pagar" id="pagar" ><a href="#" onclick="clickado()"></a></div>
```

The problem:

The .style.backgroundImage just does not change to "imagens/pagar-clickado.jpg", the the path is correct, I do not get error in console and ('pagar')[0] is also correct too.

Comment: You are targeting the `pagar` element while your CSS targets the `a` tag.

Comment: remove the double/single quotes in url("imagens/...

Comment: I change to:
<a href="#" id="pagar" onclick="clickado()"></a>

and works! thanks A1rPun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you wanted to target the `a` element inside the `div.pagar`.
You can do something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="pagar" ><a href="#" id="pagar" onclick="clickado()"></a></div>
```

Javascript

```
function clickado() {
    document.getElementById('pagar').style.backgroundImage = 'url("imagens/pagar-clickado.jpg")';
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Something so simple, but even passing the code a thousand times, go unnoticed.

Answer (score 3):

You can try add new style class for the event click:

```
 .pagar.click a:hover {
 background-image: url('imagens/pagar-clickado.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

> And change the function javascript:

```
    function clickado() {
    document.getElementById('pagar').classList.add('click');
}
```

With the new [api](http://html5doctor.com/the-classlist-api/) for working with classes, it is more easier

Answer (score 2):

You could write a much better solution attaching a class with your javascript to the '.pagar' element, for example "clicked". Then you could add a couple of lines to your CSS:

```
.pagar.clicked a,
.pagar.clicked a:hover {
    background-image: url('imagens/pagar-clickado.jpg');
}
```

This is the javascript of course:

```
<script>
function clickado() {
document.getElementsByClassName('pagar')[0].className += 'clicked';
}
</script>
```

I learned that, to keep code simple and mantainable, moving style definition to CSS (removing it from javascript) is usually the best practice to follow.

Comment: When you click the `a` multiple times you end up with the `div` (not even the `a` element) having its className like `'clickedclickedclicked'`. And he has already an image for hover.